# Batch Fetching inside a normal find operation in EclipseLink

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink, glassfish-3

I would like to use the
    @QueryHint(name=QueryHints.BATCH, value="pi.jrnls")
annotation together with the primary key @Id lookups. 
Where do I put the annotation? It looks like I can only put it inside a @NamedQuery. But the default pk lookup does not have a @NamedQuery of course.

```
@Entity
@Table(schema="prd", name="PRDITEM", uniqueConstraints= {@UniqueConstraint(columnNames= {"prditmNO"})})
@Cache(expiry=com.quoka.qis.lib.persistence.Constants.SHORT_CACHE_PERIODE_MS)
@NamedQuery(name = "PrdItem.findByNo", query = "select pi from PrdItem pi where pi.no = ?1",
    hints={
        @QueryHint(name=QueryHints.BATCH, value="pi.jrnls"),
        @QueryHint(name=QueryHints.BATCH, value="pi.bookings")//,
    }
)
public class PrdItem {....


@Id 
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name="prditmID", insertable = false, nullable=false, unique=true) 
private Long id;
```

Answer (score 1):

EclipseLink has a BatchFetch annotation you can add to the mapping: 
  http://eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.4/jpa/extensions/a_batchfetch.htm

JPA 2.0 also has a find signature that takes in the class, key and properties map.

Comment: Sorry, i did not tell. I'm using eclipselink 2.0. There is no batchfetch.

Comment: BatchFetch annotation was added in EclipseLink 2.1.  EclipseLink 2.0 has JPA 2.0 support, so you can still pass in parameters to the find method available on the EclipseLink EntityManagerImpl if you are using the JPA 1.0 persistence jar.  You can also add batch fetching to the mapping using a descriptor customizer and call useBatchReading() on it: http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Advanced_JPA_Development/Customizers